# javascript: summing even members of Fibonacci series

Tags: javascript, arrays, fibonacci

Yet Another (Project Euler) Fibonacci Question: Using (vanilla) javascript, I'm trying to sum the even numbers <= a given limit:

First, something is wrong with my 'if' statement, as some of the results (below) are wrong:

```
function fibonacciSum(limit) {
    var limit = limit;
    var series = [1,2];
    var sum = 0;
    var counter = 0;

    for (var i=1; i<=33; i++) { // 33 is arbitrary, because I know this is more than enough
        var prev1 = series[series.length-1];
        var prev2 = series[series.length-2];
        var newVal = prev1+prev2;

        series.push(newVal);
        counter ++;
        console.log("series "+ counter + " is: " + series);

        if (series[i] % 2 === 0 && series[i] <= limit) { // intending to sum only even values less than/equal to arbitrary limit
            // sum = sum + series[i];
            sum += series[i];
        }

        /*
            var sum = series.reduce(function(a,b) {
                /*
                    possible to filter here for even numbers? something like:
                    if (a %2 === 0)
                */
                return a+b;
            });
        */
        console.log("SUM " + counter + ": " + sum);
    } // for loop
} // fibonacci

fibonacciSum(4000000);
```

Results:

series 1 is: 1,2,3
SUM 1: 2
series 2 is: 1,2,3,5
SUM 2: 2
series 3 is: 1,2,3,5,8
SUM 3: 2 // looking for a '10' here
series 4 is: 1,2,3,5,8,13
SUM 4: 10
series 5 is: 1,2,3,5,8,13,21
SUM 5: 10
series 6 is: 1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34
SUM 6: 10 // looking for '44' here

Can someone please explain why neither of these working as intended?

```
if (series[i] % 2 === 0) { ...
```

... or

```
if (series[i] % 2 === 0 && series[i] <= limit) { ...
```

And secondly, as you can see I had also tried to use series.reduce(... but I can't figure how to sum only the even values; is that doable/cleaner?

Thank you,

Whiskey T.

Comment: Your loop is adding the preceding value into sum, which is why any even number added at the last position gets added only in the next iteration. Do this instead, as the first two numbers are precalculated, initialize the sum to 2, then simply compare newValue for even check, instead of series[i]. By the way, you really don't need an array for this at all.

Comment: Side-note that you cannot nest comment blocks in JavaScript: your "inner" `*/` just after `if (a %2 === 0)` closes both previous opening comments. (This is why most IDEs map the "comment" shortcut to `//` on every line.)

Comment: You could get rid of the 33 and just break when you hit the limit.

Comment: @HazardouS Thank you; I see that now (sums accurate in next iteration, though I'll prob have to stare at this for a minute to see why ;) ... as to checking newVal for even, if memory serves, I tried this, but of course I still would have sums out of sync with iterations. Thanks again

Comment: @msanford just wanted to thank you for your time, but yes I'm aware; that was only for the post :)

Comment: @SelçukCihan Indeed, using an arbitrary value to limit the if condition's iterator is cheating but I couldn't figure how to limit iteration more elegantly, thought I was approaching recursion confusion. I did also try to use a break, and while it was within the loop, it was an else statement (if newVal <= limit, else break) which threw an error. So my thought was to temporarily cheat that iterator condition to make some progress in generating sums. Thanks for your comment, appreciated.

Comment: @HazardouS The two changes you suggested did the job, so I have my answer. Now I'm ready to study your solution below, so I can learn an alternative concept, one which avoids my cheat - arbitrarily limiting the iterations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you...

```js
var fibonacciSum = function(limit) {
    var nMinus2 = 1, nMinus1 = 2, evensFound = [2], sum = nMinus1;
    while (sum <= limit){
        var n = nMinus1 + nMinus2;
        if (n % 2 == 0){
            sum += n;
            if (sum > limit){
                break;
            }
            evensFound.push(n);
        }
        nMinus2 = nMinus1;
        nMinus1 = n;
    }

    console.log("Evens found - " + evensFound);
  
  return evensFound;
};

var evensFound1 = fibonacciSum(4),
    evensFound2 = fibonacciSum(10),
    evensFound3 = fibonacciSum(60),
    evensFound4 = fibonacciSum(1000);

$(evenResults).append(evensFound1 
                      + "<br/>" + evensFound2
                     + "<br/>" + evensFound3
                     + "<br/>" + evensFound4);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="evenResults"></div>
```

Comment: I studied/played with this a little, dumped the jQ (which is not essential here, and because I'm working vanilla), and so I'll give this the check because it's enlightening, and while it's a slight departure from my approach, I had in mind to solve it using a while loop, so it makes sense to this newbie, and this also eliminates the iteration limit cheat I initially relied upon. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

No need for arrays. Use three variables for let's say previous, current and next numbers in fibonacci sequence.

We can also begin the sequence with 2 an 3 because there are no other even numbers that will affect the result.

We initialize the sum of even numbers with 2 because it's the current number and it's even. In a `do...while` we advance with the numbers in sequence and if the new numbers are even we add them to the sum. Stop when limit is reached.

```
function fibEvenSum(limit) {
  var prev = 1, 
      current = 2, 
      next;

  var sum = 2;

  do {
     next = prev + current;
     prev = current;
     current = next;

     if (current >= limit)
       break;

     if (current % 2 == 0) 
       sum += current;
  } while (true)

  return sum;
}
```

This algorithm can be improved using properties of odd and even numbers:

```
odd + odd = even
even + even = even
even + odd = odd
```

Comment: I wanted to first see it through using an array, as that's where my comprehension/conception is presently. I will study this solution as well, and thanks for the lesson, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A solution in the spirit of the one your attempted — with arrays — though as pointed out, they are not necessary.

```
var i = 0, sequence = [1, 2], total = 0;

while (sequence.slice(-1)[0] < 4000000) {
    sequence.push(sequence.slice(-1)[0] + sequence.slice(-2)[0]);
}

for ( i; i <= sequence.length; i++ ) {
    if ( sequence[i] % 2 === 0 ) {
        total += sequence[i];
    }
}
```